# Conditional formatting based on condition on a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have Data like this and I want to create a matrix visual. Since I need the Amount and Percentage in one column inside the matrix, I have created the following structured table in Power BI:

| Description | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Sales Amount | 50000 |
| Sales Percentage | 12% |
| Sales Amount | 25000 |
| Sales Percentage | 25% |
| Sales Amount | 75000 |
| Sales Percentage | 64% |

Since it's not possible to store different format types in a single column in Power BI the percentage is stored as decimals and I created a measure to change the format based on the description column with the following code:

```
Value_formated = 
VAR Val = SUM ( Table[Value] )
RETURN
SWITCH (
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Description] ),
"Sales Amount", FORMAT ( Val, "0" ),
"Sales Percentage", FORMAT ( Val, "0.00%" ))
```

My question is how am I able to create a conditional formating to change the underlying color based on the percentage Value? Like for example if the percentage is negative, the percentage field should be red and if positive green. But since percentage is mixed with total number, how can I only filter the percentages? I have tried the following guide: https://xyloslearning.com/en/power-bi-using-a-measure-to-set-up-conditional-formatting/ but I couldn't select the coloring measure maybe because there are two different formats? Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that your measure gives you the desired results, have you looked at [Microsoft's documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting) on the subject? That article mentions you can attempt the formatting with a formula if you have multiple criteria, but I have not tried this out myself.

[This post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Conditional-Formatting-Quirks/m-p/929788/highlight/false#M445561) may also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Create a format measure as follows:

```
Format = 
VAR v = MIN ( 'Table'[Value] )
VAR d = MIN ( 'Table'[Description] )

RETURN

SWITCH(TRUE(),
d =  "Sales Percentage" && v < 0, 0,
d =  "Sales Percentage" && v >= 0, 1,
2)
```

Apply conditional formatting as follows:

[image]